# Moving from webserver in Windows to Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, nginx

I've had a nginx web server in windows and are now trying to just move it to an Ubuntu 14.04 nginx web server. I thought it might just be to move the html catalog and the nginx.conf file to the new server and it would work. But it looks like nginx on Ubuntu can't handle javascript. Is that the case?

What is the easiest way of doing this?

I'm new to this so please bear with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware (considering I did it last week), Nginx supports JavaScript just fine.

**HTML**

What I would do here is version control with `git` https://git-scm.com/, upload to a git server like [Github](https://github.com) from your Windows machine. Then simply pull down to your Ubuntu machine

**Nginx**

I would advise *not* simply moving your nginx.conf file. If you're hellbent, **copy** it, but *do not* move it. Always retain the original copy. Mind you, your paths will change quite a bit moving from Windows to Ubuntu, so chances are you're much better off just reconfiguring on Ubuntu using what you already know.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I now got it running. I did'n have correct path to one of my html locations in the nginx.conf that made a "require" call to fail, and that is why I thought javascript didn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem. If it helped, don't forget to mark as answered!